# Error when trying to run Rails app on Mac OS X

Tags: ruby-on-rails

*am not a techie person per se - am trying to run a Rails app (extracted from staging environment on the cloud) on local OS X Sierra machine).

Steps done: (after having installed xCode, Command line Tools, Ruby and Rails locally)

1. $ rails server  Could not find proper version of railties (4.2.6) in any of the sources Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
2. $ bundle install (log below)
3. $ gem install bundler --pre (log below)

-- LOG FOR POINT 2 --

```
The latest bundler is 1.16.0.pre.2, but you are currently running 1.15.4.
To update, run `gem install bundler --pre`
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..........
Fetching version metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Fetching dependency metadata from https://rubygems.org/.
Using rake 11.3.0
Using i18n 0.7.0
Fetching json 1.8.3
Installing json 1.8.3 with native extensions
Using minitest 5.9.1
Using thread_safe 0.3.5
Using builder 3.2.2
Using erubis 2.7.0
Using mini_portile2 2.1.0
Using rack 1.6.5
Using mime-types-data 3.2016.0521
Using arel 6.0.3
Using net-ssh 3.2.0
Using bcrypt 3.1.11
Using debug_inspector 0.0.2
Using bundler 1.15.4
Using byebug 9.0.6
Using capistrano-harrow 0.5.3
Using coffee-script-source 1.10.0
Using execjs 2.7.0
Using thor 0.19.1
Using concurrent-ruby 1.0.2
Using orm_adapter 0.5.0
Using multi_json 1.12.1
Fetching mysql2 0.4.5
Installing mysql2 0.4.5 with native extensions
Using rdoc 4.3.0
Using sass 3.4.22
Using tilt 2.0.5
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

current directory:
/Users/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/json-1.8.3/ext/json/ext/generator
/Users/sam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20170912-887-1ldzl3o.rb
extconf.rb
creating Makefile

current directory:
/Users/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/json-1.8.3/ext/json/ext/generator
make "DESTDIR=" clean

current directory:
/Users/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/json-1.8.3/ext/json/ext/generator
make "DESTDIR="
compiling generator.c
generator.c:861:25: error: use of undeclared identifier 'rb_cFixnum'
    } else if (klass == rb_cFixnum) {
                        ^
generator.c:863:25: error: use of undeclared identifier 'rb_cBignum'
    } else if (klass == rb_cBignum) {
                        ^
generator.c:975:5: warning: division by zero is undefined [-Wdivision-by-zero]
    rb_scan_args(argc, argv, "01", &opts);
    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/sam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/include/ruby-2.4.0/ruby/ruby.h:2147:9: note:
expanded from macro 'rb_scan_args'
        rb_scan_args0(argc,argvp,fmt,\
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/sam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/include/ruby-2.4.0/ruby/ruby.h:2333:9: note:
expanded from macro 'rb_scan_args0'
                     (rb_scan_args_verify(fmt, varc), vars))
                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/sam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/include/ruby-2.4.0/ruby/ruby.h:2205:11: note:
expanded from macro 'rb_scan_args_verify'
        verify = rb_scan_args_verify_count(fmt, varc); \
                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
note: (skipping 4 expansions in backtrace; use -fmacro-backtrace-limit=0 to see
all)
/Users/sam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/include/ruby-2.4.0/ruby/ruby.h:2171:6: note:
expanded from macro 'rb_scan_args_count_hash'
     rb_scan_args_count_block(fmt, ofs, varc, vari) : \
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/sam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/include/ruby-2.4.0/ruby/ruby.h:2166:6: note:
expanded from macro 'rb_scan_args_count_block'
     rb_scan_args_count_end(fmt, ofs, varc, vari) : \
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/sam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/include/ruby-2.4.0/ruby/ruby.h:2162:12: note:
expanded from macro 'rb_scan_args_count_end'
    ((vari)/(!fmt[ofs] || rb_scan_args_bad_format(fmt)))
           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
generator.c:975:5: warning: division by zero is undefined [-Wdivision-by-zero]
    rb_scan_args(argc, argv, "01", &opts);
    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/sam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/include/ruby-2.4.0/ruby/ruby.h:2147:9: note:
expanded from macro 'rb_scan_args'
        rb_scan_args0(argc,argvp,fmt,\
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/sam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/include/ruby-2.4.0/ruby/ruby.h:2333:9: note:
expanded from macro 'rb_scan_args0'
                     (rb_scan_args_verify(fmt, varc), vars))
                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/sam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/include/ruby-2.4.0/ruby/ruby.h:2205:11: note:
expanded from macro 'rb_scan_args_verify'
        verify = rb_scan_args_verify_count(fmt, varc); \
                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
note: (skipping 4 expansions in backtrace; use -fmacro-backtrace-limit=0 to see
all)
/Users/sam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/include/ruby-2.4.0/ruby/ruby.h:2171:6: note:
expanded from macro 'rb_scan_args_count_hash'
     rb_scan_args_count_block(fmt, ofs, varc, vari) : \
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/sam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/include/ruby-2.4.0/ruby/ruby.h:2167:6: note:
expanded from macro 'rb_scan_args_count_block'
     rb_scan_args_count_end(fmt, ofs+1, varc, vari+1))
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/sam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/include/ruby-2.4.0/ruby/ruby.h:2162:12: note:
expanded from macro 'rb_scan_args_count_end'
    ((vari)/(!fmt[ofs] || rb_scan_args_bad_format(fmt)))
           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
generator.c:975:5: warning: division by zero is undefined [-Wdivision-by-zero]
    rb_scan_args(argc, argv, "01", &opts);
    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/sam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/include/ruby-2.4.0/ruby/ruby.h:2147:9: note:
expanded from macro 'rb_scan_args'
        rb_scan_args0(argc,argvp,fmt,\
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/sam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/include/ruby-2.4.0/ruby/ruby.h:2333:9: note:
expanded from macro 'rb_scan_args0'
                     (rb_scan_args_verify(fmt, varc), vars))
                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/sam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/include/ruby-2.4.0/ruby/ruby.h:2205:11: note:
expanded from macro 'rb_scan_args_verify'
        verify = rb_scan_args_verify_count(fmt, varc); \
                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
note: (skipping 4 expansions in backtrace; use -fmacro-backtrace-limit=0 to see
all)
/Users/sam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/include/ruby-2.4.0/ruby/ruby.h:2172:6: note:
expanded from macro 'rb_scan_args_count_hash'
     rb_scan_args_count_block(fmt, ofs+1, varc, vari+1))
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/sam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/include/ruby-2.4.0/ruby/ruby.h:2166:6: note:
expanded from macro 'rb_scan_args_count_block'
     rb_scan_args_count_end(fmt, ofs, varc, vari) : \
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/sam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/include/ruby-2.4.0/ruby/ruby.h:2162:12: note:
expanded from macro 'rb_scan_args_count_end'
    ((vari)/(!fmt[ofs] || rb_scan_args_bad_format(fmt)))
           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
generator.c:975:5: warning: division by zero is undefined [-Wdivision-by-zero]
    rb_scan_args(argc, argv, "01", &opts);
    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/sam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/include/ruby-2.4.0/ruby/ruby.h:2147:9: note:
expanded from macro 'rb_scan_args'
        rb_scan_args0(argc,argvp,fmt,\
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/sam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/include/ruby-2.4.0/ruby/ruby.h:2333:9: note:
expanded from macro 'rb_scan_args0'
                     (rb_scan_args_verify(fmt, varc), vars))
                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/sam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/include/ruby-2.4.0/ruby/ruby.h:2205:11: note:
expanded from macro 'rb_scan_args_verify'
        verify = rb_scan_args_verify_count(fmt, varc); \
                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
note: (skipping 4 expansions in backtrace; use -fmacro-backtrace-limit=0 to see
all)
/Users/sam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/include/ruby-2.4.0/ruby/ruby.h:2171:6: note:
expanded from macro 'rb_scan_args_count_hash'
     rb_scan_args_count_block(fmt, ofs, varc, vari) : \
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/sam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/include/ruby-2.4.0/ruby/ruby.h:2166:6: note:
expanded from macro 'rb_scan_args_count_block'
     rb_scan_args_count_end(fmt, ofs, varc, vari) : \
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/sam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/include/ruby-2.4.0/ruby/ruby.h:2162:12: note:
expanded from macro 'rb_scan_args_count_end'
    ((vari)/(!fmt[ofs] || rb_scan_args_bad_format(fmt)))
           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
generator.c:975:5: warning: division by zero is undefined [-Wdivision-by-zero]
    rb_scan_args(argc, argv, "01", &opts);
    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/sam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/include/ruby-2.4.0/ruby/ruby.h:2147:9: note:
expanded from macro 'rb_scan_args'
        rb_scan_args0(argc,argvp,fmt,\
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/sam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/include/ruby-2.4.0/ruby/ruby.h:2333:9: note:
expanded from macro 'rb_scan_args0'
                     (rb_scan_args_verify(fmt, varc), vars))
                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/sam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/include/ruby-2.4.0/ruby/ruby.h:2205:11: note:
expanded from macro 'rb_scan_args_verify'
        verify = rb_scan_args_verify_count(fmt, varc); \
                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
note: (skipping 4 expansions in backtrace; use -fmacro-backtrace-limit=0 to see
all)
/Users/sam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/include/ruby-2.4.0/ruby/ruby.h:2171:6: note:
expanded from macro 'rb_scan_args_count_hash'
     rb_scan_args_count_block(fmt, ofs, varc, vari) : \
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/sam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/include/ruby-2.4.0/ruby/ruby.h:2166:6: note:
expanded from macro 'rb_scan_args_count_block'
     rb_scan_args_count_end(fmt, ofs, varc, vari) : \
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/sam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/include/ruby-2.4.0/ruby/ruby.h:2162:12: note:
expanded from macro 'rb_scan_args_count_end'
    ((vari)/(!fmt[ofs] || rb_scan_args_bad_format(fmt)))
           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
generator.c:975:5: warning: division by zero is undefined [-Wdivision-by-zero]
    rb_scan_args(argc, argv, "01", &opts);
    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/sam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/include/ruby-2.4.0/ruby/ruby.h:2147:9: note:
expanded from macro 'rb_scan_args'
        rb_scan_args0(argc,argvp,fmt,\
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/sam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/include/ruby-2.4.0/ruby/ruby.h:2333:9: note:
expanded from macro 'rb_scan_args0'
                     (rb_scan_args_verify(fmt, varc), vars))
                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/sam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/include/ruby-2.4.0/ruby/ruby.h:2205:11: note:
expanded from macro 'rb_scan_args_verify'
        verify = rb_scan_args_verify_count(fmt, varc); \
                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
note: (skipping 5 expansions in backtrace; use -fmacro-backtrace-limit=0 to see
all)
/Users/sam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/include/ruby-2.4.0/ruby/ruby.h:2171:6: note:
expanded from macro 'rb_scan_args_count_hash'
     rb_scan_args_count_block(fmt, ofs, varc, vari) : \
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/sam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/include/ruby-2.4.0/ruby/ruby.h:2166:6: note:
expanded from macro 'rb_scan_args_count_block'
     rb_scan_args_count_end(fmt, ofs, varc, vari) : \
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/sam/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/include/ruby-2.4.0/ruby/ruby.h:2162:12: note:
expanded from macro 'rb_scan_args_count_end'
    ((vari)/(!fmt[ofs] || rb_scan_args_bad_format(fmt)))
           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
6 warnings and 2 errors generated.
make: *** [generator.o] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in
/Users/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/json-1.8.3 for inspection.
Results logged to
/Users/sam/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/extensions/x86_64-darwin-16/2.4.0/json-1.8.3/gem_make.out

An error occurred while installing json (1.8.3), and Bundler cannot
continue.
Make sure that `gem install json -v '1.8.3'` succeeds before bundling.

In Gemfile:
  rails was resolved to 4.2.6, which depends on
    actionmailer was resolved to 4.2.6, which depends on
      actionpack was resolved to 4.2.6, which depends on
        actionview was resolved to 4.2.6, which depends on
          rails-dom-testing was resolved to 1.0.7, which depends on
            rails-deprecated_sanitizer was resolved to 1.0.3, which depends on
              activesupport was resolved to 4.2.6, which depends on
                json
```

=== LOG FOR POINT 3 ===

```
Fetching: bundler-1.16.0.pre.2.gem (100%)
Successfully installed bundler-1.16.0.pre.2
Parsing documentation for bundler-1.16.0.pre.2
Installing ri documentation for bundler-1.16.0.pre.2
Done installing documentation for bundler after 8 seconds
1 gem installed
```

Comment: As the first log says, there is some error in installing `json` gem. Can you try running the command `gem install json -v '1.8.3'` and then run `bundle install` again?

Comment: Error generated as viewable at https://www.scribd.com/document/358815467/Error?secret_password=S0lGLW0BGowCIMxmYbyV